# compare different files and get things in common

Tags: python, list, file, compare

i have two txt files like this

```
file1.txt    file2.txt

 a           a propertya
 b           z propertyz
 c           c propertyc
 d           m propertym
 e           f propertyf
 f           w propertyw
 g           e propertye    
 etc         b propertyb
             d propertyd
             x propertyx
             g propertyg
             etc
```

(all the elements of file1 are in file2 but not the other way, file2 has all the modules and file1 just a set of modules) and i need to compare those files and get another txt file with the elements in common and they respective property, i mean

file.txt

```
a propertya
b propertyb
c propertyc
d propertyd
e propertye
f propertyf
g propertyg
```

i do not know how to do this (i am new at python), i just can make simple things, like getting list of the objects in common but i do not know how to write their respective property.

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is the same as your example, it seems like fil1.txt has the keys to a dictionary that is defined in file2.txt. You could use the following script to load file2.txt into a dict:

```
sep = " "
d = {}
with open("file2.txt", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        # strip() to get rid of unnecesary spaces/endline/etc
        key, val = line.strip().split(sep)
        d[key] = val
```

Now you can read file1.txt and get the keys from there, with the following code:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as fd:
    keys = fd.readlines()
keys = [k.strip() for k in keys]
for k in keys:
    print "%s %s" % (k, dict[k])
```

Some comments:

- sep is a variable to hold the sepparator. Usually this is a ',' char, in your case it seems to be a space ' ', but that tends to bring problems. In cases where the comma is also problematic, you can use pipe '|', or whatever weird character should never appear in your data. If you need another sepparator, you have to update your files.
- The order in which the properties are printed depends on the order of file1.txt.
- I did a simple print, which could be improved according to your needs.

**Edit:** fixed a few typos.

Comment: yes this works, thanks a lot, now i am figuring out how it works since i can do just simple things in python , thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = []
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        elements.append(line[:line.find('\n')])

newFile = open('file.txt','a')
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if elements.__contains__(line[0:1]):
            newFile.write(line)
newFile.close()
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but the output list is empty and i cant solve it :(

Comment: you have to put the full path to 'file1.txt' so for example it could be 'C:\Users\camron\Downloads\file1.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Read both files;

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    f1 = f.readlines()
f1 = [k.strip() for k in f1]  # Remove unneeded whitespace
letters = ''.join(f1)  # make it into a string of letters
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    f2 = f.readlines()
f2 = [k.strip() for k in f2]  # Remove unneeded whitespace
```

For each line in f2, check if it starts with a letter from the first file

```
lines = [ln for ln in f2 if ln[0] in letters]
```

Write the result to a file;

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write('\n'.join(lines))
```